# swift type comparison against class types

Tags: swift, reflection

It's easy to do type comparison along the lines of:

```
if foo is NSDate { ... }
```

or

```
if let bar = foo as NSDate { ... }
```

but I haven't had any luck testing an object's type against a class type.

Here's a playground that shows what I've tried:

```
import UIKit

class DateRowType : NSObject {
    static var dataType : AnyClass {
        get {
            return NSDate.self
        }
    }
}

let date = NSDate()

// never succeeds
if reflect(date).valueType is DateRowType.dataType.Type {
    print ("it's a date!")
}

// prints error 'dataType' is not a member type of 'DateRowType'
if let newDate = date as DateRowType.dataType {
    print("it's a date!")
}


// string comparison failure due to NSDate class cluster
reflect(date).valueType // __NSDate
print(DateRowType.dataType) // NSDate
```

What is the correct way to do this? Am I returning the wrong type from dataType?

Answer (score 0):

For subclasses of `NSObject` you can use `isKindOfClass()`
(as in Objective-C):

```
if date.isKindOfClass(DateRowType.dataType) {
    println ("it's a date!")
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need it to also work with Swift types like String.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the dynamicType:

```
let date = NSDate()
let str = "AnyString"

if toString(date.dynamicType) == toString(NSDate().dynamicType) {
    print ("it's a date!")
}

if toString(str.dynamicType) == toString("".dynamicType) {
    print ("it's a  string")
}
```

Comment: But NSDate() is an instance of NSDate, it isn't the class. I don't want to allocate an instance, I want to return the type.